# NativeScript App Cannot Connect To Android Emulator

Tags: node.js, android-emulator, nativescript

So after following the `get started` walk through, I have my NativeScript development environment setup with Node.js, Android JDK, Android SDK and AVD and off course the NativeScript CLI(tns). I then proceeded to create a NativeScript template app using the `tns create ...` statement and it succeeded. Then it was time to run the app, so I started up the app using `tns run android` - The emulator startered but the tns service just kept searching for a running device/emulator and eventually failed. Listing the devices revealed the following:

[image]

The device seems to be unreachable, and since I am completely new to NativeScript development, I do not know what environment factors could be causing this.

I Have the following SDK's and system images ready:

[image]

Should I try a lower version?

My understanding is that the NativeScript platform builds the project into something the emulator can run and passes it to the emulator automatically, however since it is unreachable this process is never completed.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced that myself and even though I did not find a fix, I have a workaround. Also, all other problems I encountered can be found [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/2486)

**Reason for happening**
It is to do with your specific environment and account privileges

**Workaround**

1. Open your AVD Manager as Administrator
2. Run your Emulated Android device
3. Open CMD/PS/Bash... as Administrator > CD [project directory] > `tns run android --timeout 100`

**Note:** At this point you might find that the NativeScript is running to a "Build Error" and it is exciting. Now... that is documented [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/2092). I found that creating a fresh TNS project works best than amending package.json, but you are welcome to do either.
[Native-script build error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVzTq.jpg)

4. Profit
   [Native-script successful build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRqS8.png)